# Python: Change passed variable in thread and use the new value outside the thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

sorry if someone asked this before, but I couldn't find a solution for a weird problem, I have at the moment. Like I was reading in a lot of articles, it should be possible to pass a variable to a thread in Python, change it there, and use the new value in the calling thread? But this is not working for me. I have an example code here:

```html
from threading import Thread

def change(val):
    val = False

def start():
    val = True
    t = Thread(target=change, args=(val,))
    t.start()
    t.join()

    print(val) #--> stays True but should be False

start()
```

If anyone knows what the problem is, I'm very happy for an answer.

Greetings Leuko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method, the memory address of `value` changes, so it is a different object (a local variable).

For your goal, use an object and change an attribute so the object address stays the same.

Try this code

```
from threading import Thread

def change(val):
    val[0] = False  # list address stays the same, update attribute

def start():
    val = [True] # list object
    t = Thread(target=change, args=(val,))
    t.start()
    t.join()

    print(val[0])  # False

start()
```

Note the this also applies when not using multi-threading.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked. And actually now it is very obvious why it was not working. I was thinking of creating a class object with the necessary elements, but using a list object is much more practical:)